# Error al hacer consulta con eloquent en laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de mostrar datos de una tabla que tiene relación y estoy utilizando Laravael Eloquent para la consulta.

pero me genera el sgt error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'a.nombre' in 
>       'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from articulos inner 
>       join `categorias

las tablas estan migradas de la siguente manera:

**Articulos**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateArticulosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('categoria_id');
            $table->string('codigo', 40);
            $table->string('nombre', 45);
            $table->string('descripcion', 45)->nullable();
            $table->Integer('stock');
            $table->string('imagen', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('estado', 20);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')->on('categorias')->onDelete('no action')->onUpdate('no action');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articulos');
    }
}
```

**Categorias**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre', 45);
            $table->string('descripcion', 45)->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('condicion');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categorias');
    }
}
```

**Controlador Articulos**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Articulo;

use App\Http\Requests\ArticuloFormRequest;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class ArticuloController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request) {

            $query = trim($request->get('searchText'));

            $articulos = Articulo::select('articulos as a')
                ->join('categorias as c', 'a.categoria_id', '=', 'c.id')
                ->select('a.id', 'a.nombre', 'a.codigo', 'a.stock', 'c.nombre as categoria', 'a.descripcion', 'a.imagen', 'a.estado')
                //busca en la caja de texto por el nombre o codigo
                ->where('a.nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orwhere('a.codigo', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->paginate(2)
                ->get();

            return view('bodega.articulo.index', ["articulos" => $articulos, "searchText" => $query]);

        }
    }
}
```

**vista index**

```
@extends('layoust.admin')
@section ('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <h3>
            Listado de Articulos
            <a href="articulo/create">
                <button class="btn btn-success">
                    Nuevo
                </button>
            </a>
        </h3>
        <!--se incluye la vista search, que es una barra de busqueda-->
        @include('bodega.articulo.search')
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>
                        Id
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Nombre
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Codigo
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Categoria
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Stock
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Imagen
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Estado
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Opciones
                    </th>
                </thead>
                <!--Bucle que recorre todas las articulos-->
                @foreach ($articulos as $art)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ $art->id_articulo}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $art->nombre}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $art->codigo}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $art->categoria}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $art->stock}}
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $art->estado}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Vista de busqueda**

```
<!--Abrir formulario,  y lo redicionara a la vista index de articulo y el parametro de busqueda va hacer con
    el parametro get,codigo con laravel colletive-->
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'bodega/articulo','method'=>'GET', 'autocomplete'=>'off', 'role'=>'search'))!!}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchText" placeholder="Buscar.." value="{{$searchText}}">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>           
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que en el select estas intentando ponerle un alias a la tabla completa, cuando ahi solo te va a servir para poner alias a una o varias columnas especificas del modelo **Articulo**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente:

Primero tu consulta debería quedar así

```
$query = trim($request->get('searchText'));

            $articulos = Articulo::from('articulos as a')
                ->select('a.id', 'a.nombre', 'a.codigo', 'a.stock', 
                         'c.nombre as categoria', 'a.descripcion', 
                         'a.imagen', 'a.estado')
                ->join('categorias as c', 'a.categoria_id', '=', 'c.id')
                //busca en la caja de texto por el nombre o codigo
                ->where('a.nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orwhere('a.codigo', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->paginate(2)
                ->get();

 return view('bodega.articulo.index', ["articulos" => $articulos, "searchText" => $query]);
```

**INDICACIONES**

> 1. Tu consulta no resultaba por que en el `select` solo puedes colocarle el alias a las columnas de la tabla pero no a la tabla
>      completa
> 2. Usa el método `from()`, para que justo despues de invocar al Método `Articulo` indiques que a la tabla `articulos` le pondrás el alias de
>      `a`
> 3. Opino que deberías mover el `select` para que quede justo después del método `from` para que se mejore su lectura, al menos yo siempre
>      trabajo mis consultas así como te indico

Ya con las observaciones anteriores te debería estar funcionando

Answer (score 3):

Cambia:

```
Articulo::select('articulos as a')
```

por

```
Articulo::from('articulos as a')
```

Answer (score 2):

Si me falta practicar más sobre las consultas en eloquent. Ahora mirando sus respuestas tuve una idea de hacer la consulta mas comoda, utilice esta:

```
$articulos = Articulo::with(['categoria'])->get();
```

Con esta consulta ya me envía la relación que tengo con la tabla categorías.

Comment: exacto por que aquí estas empleado el concepto de **eagger loading** que se ayuda a  su vez de las relaciones de Laravel como `hasMany` y `belongsTo` y lo que pasas en el método with es el nombre del método que tienes declarado, **buena alternativa**